# How to edit mulltidimensional array elements in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

this is my array:

```
  $array=  array(3) { 
[0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> "one"   ["com"]=>  "com1"  ["id"]=> "1" } 
[1]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> "two"  ["com"]=>  "com2"   ["id"]=> "2"  }
[2]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> "three"  ["com"]=>  "com3" ["id"]=> "3"  }
```

I need posibility to change values of name and com for specific id. I try some examples from Stack questions:

1.[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179961/updating-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

```
foreach($array as &$value){
    if($value['id'] == 1){
        $value['name'] = 'test';
        $value['com'] = 'test';
        break; // Stop the loop after we've found the item
    }
}
```

But it don't work. no error but no result too.

2.[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631908/multidimensional-array-find-and-update-the-value-using-php)

Again,no error message,but no result...

I also try a lot of other examples from Stack but fake,and finaly to write a question..

Buy,
P

Comment: So what is the problem? What do you want to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: the first example should work just fine, its just important `$value['id']` really equates to `1`

Comment: Hi, problem is that I can't change values of array elements , I try with foreach to loop array,and then for chosen ID ,to change values for name and com keys... Maybe that is not posible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not changing your array value that's why it's-not giving you desired output.  Try this:-

```
foreach($array as $key => &$value){
    if($key == 1){
        $array[1]['name'] = 'test';// change value to original array
        $array[1]['com'] = 'test'; //change value to original array
        break; // Stop the loop after we've found the item
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved! Tnx for answer

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Why shouldn't OP's code work? He passes the value by reference?! OP's code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
    if($array[$i]['id'] == 1) {
        $array[$i]['name'] = 'test';
        $array[$i]['com'] = '';
        break;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the array on creation I would recommend shifting the id to the array's key identifier. Would make life a lot easier to just do:

`$array[1]['name'] = 'test';`

Otherwise use the for loop posted above and look it up. (Right awnser)